# I am trying to convert a CSV file to ANSI format with Textedit on Mac OS High Sierra version 10.13

Tags: mac, conversion, csv, utf-8, ansi

I have to provide CSV files with Energy Manager consumption data to an Energy Management System (EMS) and I am working on a Mac with OS High Sierra Version 10.13.

I work with LibreOffice and with the TextEdit application. Both won’t deliver the ANSI code, even if I think to have found the proper export options. For LibreOffice I use Save As …, check the Filter Settings box and choose instead of Unicode the Character set of Western Europe (Ascii US). On TextEdit I use the Menu > Preferences > Open & Save Tab > Plain Text File Encoding and choose then Saving Files in Western (Windows Latin 1). In both cases I still get UTF-8 as my EMS Support says and as I can see myself by bringing the file to my PC and opening it with Notepad++.

I am now trying to find text editors for Mac that are more sophisticated than TextEdit but still then, even for Textedit and Libreoffice it seems that I found the solution and it just doesn’t work. Do I have to choose for still an other character set in Libreoffice of Textedit?

I feel stuck and need this conversion for my Business Model to get my datalogger output into the Energy Management System (EMS) application on the Cloud.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/701882/what-is-ansi-format